# Configurar 2 aplicações na mesma URL

Tags: iis

Bom dia!

Tenho um IIS com uma aplicação(1) publicada externalmente :

> site1.com.br

Porém possuo outra aplicação(2) que não está publicada externamente, e preciso publica-la.

Minha duvida é: Consigo publicar essa aplicação(2) na mesma url da aplicação(1) apenas diferenciando por "/aplicacao2"?

Exemplo:

> site1.com.br/aplicacao2

Preciso realizar algum redirecionamento?De que forma faço isso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples, basta voce adicionar uma aplicacao na sua ja existente, como na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]